# Python replace in JSON list with for loop?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, replace, formatting

I'm quite new to python 3, and I'm developing a REST API to format some characters in a JSON of numerous strings (thousands sometimes) , the JSON has this structure:

```
  [
  [
    "city",
    "Street 158 No 96"
  ],
  [
    "city",
    "st 144 11a 11 ap 104"
  ],
  [
    "city",
    "Street83 # 85  - 22"
  ],
  [
    "city",
    "str13 #153  -  81"
  ],
  [
    "city",
    "street1h # 24 - 29"
  ]
]
```

So what I did to replace this on excel macros was.

```
text = Replace(text, "st", " street ", , , vbTextCompare)
For i = 0 To 9 Step 1
    text = Replace(text, "street" & i, " street " & i, , , vbTextCompare)
    text = Replace(text, "st" & i, " street " & i, , , vbTextCompare)
```

This would format every cell to 'street #' no matter the number, now the problem is when I try to do this with python, right now I have learned how to replace multiple values on a list like so:

```
addressList= []
for address in request.json:

    address = [element

    .replace('st', 'street ')
    .replace('street1­', 'street 1')
    .replace('street2', 'street 2')
    .replace('street3', 'street 3')
    .replace('street4', 'street 4')
    .replace('street5­', 'street 5')
     

     #and so on for st too

    for element in address]

    addressList.append(address)
```

This method is not just long but also really ugly, I'd like to do something like what I had before, but I can't seem to be able to use a for inside the replace, should I do it outside?

Thank you for helping.

**--EDIT--**

edited the json format so it's valid.

tried both revliscano and The fourth bird's replies they both work, currently i'm using revliscano's method as it allows me to create the list from my original Json in just 'one line'

Comment: That's not valid JSON structure. `{}` surrounds objects, which are in `key: value` format.

Comment: You can check your JSON format valid or not in this link https://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regular expression to solve this. Try with the following

```
import re

address_list = [[re.sub(r'(?:st ?(\d)?\b)|(?:street(\d))', r'street \1', element)
                for element in address]
                for address in request.json]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple replace calls, you could use a pattern  matching `st` with optional `reet` and an optional space, then capture 1+ digits in a group.

```
\bst(?:reet)? ?(\d+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yyZIqe/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fUSvMQ)

In the replacement use the capturing group `street \1` using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

*Example code for a single element*

```
import re
element = re.sub(r"\bst(?:reet)? ?(\d+)\b", r"street \1", "st 5")
print (element)
```

*Output*

```
street 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions mixed with dictionary to make it faster.

I use a function like this in one of my programs

```
import re
def multiple_replace(adict, text):
    regex = re.compile("|".join(map(re.escape, adict.keys())))   
    return regex.sub(lambda match: adict[match.group(0)], text)
```

`adict` is the dictionary in which you have the mappings of the charaters you want to replace.

For you, it can be

```
adict = {
    'street1­': 'street 1'
    'street2':'street 2',
    'street3': 'street 3',
    'street4': 'street 4',
    'street5­': 'street 5',
}
```

Of course you can't use the exact same function. You will have to write another regular expression according to your needs, like `@The fourth bird` did